# splinter: visible dropdown is clickable but not selectable

Tags: python, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, splinter

I am trying to select something from a dropdown on a modal via splinter. I have no problem finding this dropdown, e.g. :

```
(Pdb) dropdown = next(i for i in my_browser.find_by_xpath('//select[@name="existing.widgets.user:list"]') if i.visible)
```

(the page I'm dealing with actually has multiple, identical modals, so I have to get the current, visible one. Sigh..)

The dropdown can be clicked:

```
(Pdb) dropdown.visible
True
(Pdb) dropdown.click()  //succeeds and displays menu
(Pdb)
```

...but trying to select on it fails, even though it's supposedly visible!

```
(Pdb) dropdown.select('my_val')
*** ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Stacktrace:
    at fxdriver.preconditions.visible (file:///tmp/tmp6tSmOc/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:9587)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_ (file:///tmp/tmp6tSmOc/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12257)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmp6tSmOc/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12274)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmp6tSmOc/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12279)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///tmp/tmp6tSmOc/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12221)
(Pdb) dropdown.visible
True  // what???
(Pdb)
```

I'm pretty sure the argument to select is correct, so I'm at a loss about what's going on here.

If all else fails, is there something clever I can do with xpaths? Or do I need to try finding/interacting with the element another way?

A partial screenshot of the HTML situation: http://pasteboard.co/1I30ljRl.png

Comment: Have you clicked the dropdown before making a select?

Comment: Also show the HTML representation of the select element or share a link to the website where we can observe it. Thanks.

Comment: I tried clicking first; same error :-(

Comment: also, added screenshot. Site isn't deployed/accessible outside my company, so I can't provide a link.

Comment: Thanks, what about using `dropdown.select(value='my_val')` instead?

Comment: Nope; same problem. Interestingly, my code works fine for the first two identical modals on the page, but fails when attempting to populate the third. Looking into whether it's the order of the modals or the actual modals..

Comment: ...order doesn't seem to matter; the same ones fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the multiple modals are what did me in.

Given my dropdown with name `'existing.widgets.user:list'` and the desired `my_val`, the failing `select` call, at its source, has:

`find_by_xpath('//select[@name="%s"]/option[@value="%s"]' % (dropdown['name'], my_val).click()`

Now, it turns out that this `find_by_xpath` actually returns multiple/duplicate options, probably from the multiple modals!

```
(Pdb) blah=my_browser.find_by_xpath('//select[@name="%s"]/option[@value="%s"]' % (dropdown['name'], my_val)
(Pdb) blah
[<splinter.driver.webdriver.WebDriverElement object at 0x7f7205ff3750>, <splinter.driver.webdriver.WebDriverElement object at 0x7f7205ff39d0>, <splinter.driver.webdriver.WebDriverElement object at 0x7f7205ff38d0>, <splinter.driver.webdriver.WebDriverElement object at 0x7f7205ff3610>]
(Pdb) [bl.value for bl in blah]
[u'my_val', u'my_val', u'my_val', u'my_val']
(Pdb) [bl.visible for bl in blah]
[False, True, False, False]
```

I thought I could fix this by accessing the options via the correct modal (e.g, with the specific form class) instead of through the whole page; i.e., starting with something like

```
form = my_browser.find_by_xpath('//form[@id="{0}"]'.format(my_current_modal))
```

...and THEN trying

```
dropdown = form.find_by_xpath(...)
dropdown.select(...)
etc.
```

But it led to the same problem; still multiple elements being found, and still failing! So, I resorted to visibility checks, which actually worked:

```
opts = form.find_by_xpath('//select[@name="%s"]/option[@value="%s"]' % (dropdown['name'], my_val)
next(opt for opt in opts if opt.visible).click()
```

Perhaps something I'm still missing here...or even something buggy with Splinter, but at least it works!